# use css `letter-spacing` while keep Chinese Em dash connected

Tags: css, spacing, cjk

I'm using `letter-spacing: 10px` to avoid writing "s o m e t h i n g   l i k e   t h i s".

It works great. But `letter-spacing` also introduce spaces between [Chinese Em dash (破折号, —— )](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_punctuation#Em_dash).

The render result is ugly since it split the Em dash into two parts. And The Em dash should be connected.

Here is the example:

```css
p { letter-spacing: 10px; }
```

```html
<p>这句话不是我说的。<br />——鲁迅</p>
```

How can I add spaces between every characters but still keep things like Em dash connected?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible without adding additional markup, is wrapping the dashes in a `span` and having an alternative `letter-spacing` value for spans an option? (You could add the spans manually or programmatically with JS)

Comment: @DBS The best result should be: the two dashes are connected but keep current width. If it is not possible, I would prefer at least these two characters connected without spacing.

Comment: Ah, after some google search, a simple but not pretty workaround would be: use U+2E3A TWO EM DASH "⸺" as chinese em dash instead.

Comment: @DBS Yes, `<span style="letter-spacing: 0;">—</span>—` works. as another workaround....

Answer (score 1):

After some Google search I got this: A simple but not pretty workaround would be using `U+2E3A TWO EM DASH` as Em dash (破折号) instead of the default one your IME outputed. You may copy it from here: ⸺

```css
p { letter-spacing: 10px; }
```

```html
<p>这句话不是我说的。<br />⸺鲁迅</p>
```

Comment: Also note that U+2E3A may not work in some fonts. And they may be shown as blocks / question marks when user using old fonts (operating systems).